# Qt - change property from a component in a different qml file

Tags: qt, qml

**Update 1**

The idea is to be able to change the front and back of CardForm from main.qml because i want to be able to use multiple CardForm instances. I tried to do what they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401248/changing-property-of-element-from-other-qml-file) but it doesnt work.

Here is the code:

CardForm.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Flipable {
    id: sCard
    width: 75
    height: 200

    property bool flipped: false
    property string front: "Front"
    property string back: "Back"

    property alias callFront : front
    property alias callBack : back

    front: Rectangle{
        id: front
        anchors.fill: sCard
        border.width: 2
        border.color: "black"
        radius: 5
        Text{
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: sCard.front
        }
    }

    back: Column{
        Rectangle{
            id: back
            anchors.fill: sCard
            radius: 5
            border.width: 2
            border.color: "black"
            Text{
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: sCard.front
            }
            Text{
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: sCard.front
            }
        }
    }

    transform: Rotation{
        id: flip
        origin.x: sCard.width
        origin.y: sCard.height/2
        axis.x: 0; axis.y: 1; axis.z: 0     // set axis.y to 1 to rotate around y-axis
        angle: 0    // the default angle
    }

    states: State {
        name: "back"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: flip
            angle: 180
        }
        when: sCard.flipped
    }

    transitions: Transition{
        NumberAnimation {
            target: flip
            property: "angle"
            duration: 200
        }
    }

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: sCard.flipped = !sCard.flipped
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Neuro Seed")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Column {
            CardForm{
                id: test
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                test.callFront: "Hello World!"
                test.callBack: "Bonjour le Monde!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the error messages:

SHGetSpecialFolderPath() failed for standard location "Shared Configuration", clsid=0x1c. ()

qrc:/main.qml:17:13: QML CardForm: back is a write-once property

qrc:/main.qml:17:13: QML CardForm: front is a write-once property

qrc:/main.qml:16:9: QML Column: Cannot specify top, bottom, verticalCenter, fill or centerIn anchors for items inside Column. Column will not function.

the c1.getFront() and getBack() were from a C++ class that I made. I changed these to "Hello World!" and "Bonjour le Monde!"

Comment: Ugh... There is a lot. Try to explain again, what exactly you were trying to achieve. It all starts with line *9* and *10* in your `CardForm` where you try to overwrite the properties of the `Flipable`, but it is unlikely the end of the story. Please also include all error messages.

Comment: `c1` appears to be undefined where you reference it in main.qml

Comment: You try to assign something to a `readonly` property (`property alias callFront : front` creates a readonly access to the object with id `front`)

Comment: This code is broken in so many places, that I don't see where to start. You should restart almost from the beginning, take baby-steps and try out your code whenever you change something. If you then find some problems you can't solve, you might ask again. If you do, *please* add the error-messages.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the post and a bit of the code, @derM for me the code works and I do take baby steps while I write and change it, could you please elaborate on how it is broken? I'm also trying to make it so that the property is not read only, I could not find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after many hours of struggling I figured out that to create a property which is accessible by other .qml files you must create a `property alias name: id.property`. The id must point towards an existing instance of a object in your code and the property of this instance that you wish to be able to change from the outside. So in my case it would be like so:

`CardForm.qml`

```
Flipable {
    id: sCard
    width: 75
    height: 200

    property bool flipped: false
    property alias frontText : front.text

    front: Rectangle{
        id: front
        anchors.fill: sCard
        border.width: 2
        border.color: "black"
        radius: 5
        Text{
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: frontText
        }
    }
}
```

and in the `main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Neuro Seed")

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            CardForm{
                id: test
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                frontText: "Hello World!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```